# How to do diagonal matrix

Tags: java

I've been trying to do diagonal matrix for some time now but im stuck. It should look like this, with 2 user inputs (negative numbers on left and positive on right. Also, it has to start and end with zero. This is as far as i gotten. How can i make diagonal matrix using arrays?

0 1 2 3 4

-2 0 2 4 6

-6 -3 0 3 6

-12 -8 -4 0  4

-20 -15 -10 -5 0

```
public static void main(String[] args)    {

    Scanner skener = new Scanner (System.in);



      int m, n;

      do
      {
      System.out.print("m: ");
      m = skener.nextInt();

      System.out.print("n: ");
      n = skener.nextInt();


      }while(m>=10);


        for (int x=1; x<=m; x++) { //ponavljajoča zanka za m


            for (int y=1; y<=n; y++) { //ponavljajoča zanka za n





                System.out.print(x*y); //zmnožek števcev (x in y)
                System.out.print("    "); //gre v novo vrsto

                if(n==5) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do here, can you explain more clearly? Also, what exactly is the problem with the code you have written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't use arrays like you talked about, but prints the matrix like your code sample does.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printDiagonalMatrix(5, 5);
}
public static void printDiagonalMatrix(int width, int height) {
    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
            if (col != 0)
                System.out.print(' ');
            System.out.print((col - row) * (row + 1));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
0 1 2 3 4
-2 0 2 4 6
-6 -3 0 3 6
-12 -8 -4 0 4
-20 -15 -10 -5 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Exactly what i needed :)